# Visual Studio Performance Analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, analysis

I have an OpenGL application, which is running very well. But when i create a menu and make it visible to the scene, the startup of the application turns very slow. I would like to run a performance analysis to that function, to check where is Visual Studio spending that much time. Is it possible to get that kind of deep details into performance?

Thanks in advanced,
John

Comment: Visual Studio does come with performance tools, but I don't know if they're accessible outside of the "ultimate" edition. Which edition are you using?

Comment: ultimate edition. I know how to run a performance test, but i cannot the amount of %% CPU spent on each function

Comment: Did you open the call graph part of perf analysis? There's also a function list function,...

Comment: going to take a look. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the ANTS Performance Profiler 8 - I know it can zero in to the function/line to show you where the bottleneck is.  They do provide a free trial and it is easy to use.

Comment: This does not answer the question.